# What are the maximum points that an F1 driver can achieve in 2022?

Tags: formula-1

We have 22 races, and three of the races have a sprint race. So, here is my calculation:

22 main races = 25 points (first place) x 22 = 550 points

3 sprint races = 8 points (first place) x 3 = 24 points

22 fastest laps for the main race = 1 point (fastest lap) x 22 = 22 points

Total maximum points = 550 + 24 + 22 = **596 points**

Is this the correct maximum points?

Answer (score 2):

From the [sporting regulations](https://www.fia.com/regulation/category/110):

> 6.4 Points for both titles will be awarded at each Event according to the following scale:

| **Position** | **Points** |
| --- | --- |
| 1st | 25 |
| 2nd | 18 |
| 3rd | 15 |
| 4th | 12 |
| 5th | 10 |
| 6th | 8 |
| 7th | 6 |
| 8th | 4 |
| 9th | 2 |
| 10th | 1 |

> In addition to the above, one point will be awarded to the driver who achieved the fastest
> valid lap time of the race and to the constructor whose car he was driving, provided he
> was in the top ten (10) positions of the final race classification (see Article 6055). No
> point will be awarded if the fastest valid lap time is achieved by a driver who was
> classified outside the top ten positions, or if the leader has completed less than 50% of
> the scheduled race distance.
>
> At those Events where a sprint qualifying session takes place, points for both titles will be awarded based on the final sprint qualifying session classification according to the following scale:

| **Position** | **Points** |
| --- | --- |
| 1st | 8 |
| 2nd | 7 |
| 3rd | 6 |
| 4th | 5 |
| 5th | 4 |
| 6th | 3 |
| 7th | 2 |
| 8th | 1 |

This means a "perfect" score for a sprint-race weekend is 34 and 26 on a non-sprint event. So yes those calculations are correct - with a couple of caveats. Firstly this is no longer true now that we're 5 races in and since no-one is currently on the maximum the maximum possible has now decreased. Secondly this also assumes that the schedule remains at 22 races - the 2022 season was originally intended to be **23** races long and was only reduced to 22 when Russia was cancelled and the FIA has now [confirmed](https://www.formula1.com/en/latest/article.formula-1-to-race-at-22-grands-prix-in-2022.5ySj1LGnDVesfBDHI1Kc3c.html) that it won't be replaced.

Comment: Apologies, as I don't follow F1, but what driver(s) currently have the highest point total and if they won everything from now on, what could they possibly make, unlikely as that may be?

Comment: @CGCampbell Current championship leader is Charles Leclerc on 104pts after 5 rounds. There's 17 races left (and two sprints) so he can add another 458pts for a theoretical maximum of 562